# DNS on SUNOS 4.1.4 / Solaris

Tags: solaris, resolv.conf

On SUNOS(not solaris)
the dns works only with nis enabled(sic!)
I have did so

modified yp Makefile and added B=-b and put # on next B

```
ypinit -m   OK

route add default 10.0.0.1 OK

ypwhich ok 
ypcat  ok
ping ok

telnet ok
```

vi /etc/resolv.conf

```
order local, nis, bind
nameserver 10.0.0.1
```

But if try a resolv with nslookup it timeouts. And also ftp does not resolve names. Why?
If I try ftp with an IP address (network and internet), it works.

Why doesn´t it resolve names?

Comment: I could swear the order directive is in nsswitch.conf and not in resolve.conf...

Comment: No nsswitch.conf on sunos,is different

Comment: http://www.manpages.info/sunos/nsswitch.conf.4.html

Comment: SunOS 5.8           Last change: 10 Jul 2001 SUNOS post 4.1.4 are Solaris and is a different system than SunOS

Comment: I have not touched Solaris for a while...but I am pretty sure I have never seen the order directive in any Unix system being used in /etc/resolv.conf. Solaris docs. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1386/6jam5ahkg/index.html

Comment: Try this: edit `/var/yp/Makefile` on the NIS server to add `B=-b` and then remake the maps. http://www.sunhelp.org/faq/dns.html#dns25

Comment: I make the hack B=-b but nothing change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SunOS 4.x as shipped did not do DNS lookups without NIS.   There was an unsupported hack called *resolv+* that replaced files in libc.so, which you then relinked, to enable it.  You can find more about it in the [SunHelp DNS FAQ](http://www.sunhelp.org/faq/dns.html) and [older versions of the O'Reilly DNS and BIND book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xb9O5yNS5GEC&lpg=PA121&ots=M8OreNW_kv&dq=sunos%204.1%20dns%20libc%20resolv%2B&pg=PA120#v=onepage&q=sunos%204.1%20dns%20libc%20resolv%20&f=false), but I don't know if you can still find the necessary code to do this today.

Of course, you should not actually be running any SunOS 4 machine today that's connected to the internet, as it's been well over a decade since any security patches were made for it.

Comment: Interesting tidbit, Alan.

Comment: I use only for test,is a virtual machine i turn on it for 1 hour max per..week.

Answer (score 1):

1. The order directive does not work, take it out.  For SunOS 4 with the standard libc, there is a fixed order of NIS then BIND.  (If you want to use a static hosts file, be sure to rebuild the NIS database after every edit.)
2. With the standard libc, nslookup will not work.  Use ypmatch *hostname* hosts to test name resolution.
3. ftp should work if ypmatch works.  Are you using the right binary?  (/usr/ucb/ftp)